# Query by radio button ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am making a page template that should display custom post-types that have meta value that matches the page title. Meta value is added trough [Advanced Custom Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) radio buttons, but the query is not taking the meta into consideration, it's displaying all the posts. 
I've checked `$name` stores the correct string, posts have the correct value for `program` key.

Here is the query code:

```
$name = get_the_title(get_the_ID());
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'program',
            'value' => $name,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ) 
    );
$projects_q = new WP_Query($args);
```

I've even tried to wrap the 'value' value in `""` and change the `$name` to lower case but the result is the same.

```
$name = strtolower(get_the_title(get_the_ID()));
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'program',
            'value' => '"' . $name . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ) 
    );
$projects_q = new WP_Query($args);
```

Is there some special way to query posts with radio buttons?

Answer (score 2):

I tried with regular `meta_key` - `meta_value` pair and it works as it should...

```
$name = get_the_title(get_the_ID());
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'program',
    'meta_value' => $name,
    );
$projects_q = new WP_Query($args);
```